# Symfony2: how to get user's list by ROLE in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to send a log to the admins.
Thus, I want to get list of admins.
I can take a user by name for example:

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findByName('admin');
```

but how I can get it by ROLE?

Comment: The roles are stored in a serialized array in the `roles` column, so you won't be able to retrieve all users by role easily. You could add a `admin` boolean column that is set to true for admin users.